DBDateTimePicker and entering the date from the keyboard
I have a DBDateTimePicker component.
If I drop down the Calendar and select a date from the list, then in the OnChange event I have this new date (and in the dataset in a given field, there is also this new date).
But, if I place the cursor in this field and type a date by keyboard, then in the OnChange event I still have the previous date.
Do I need to refresh this date somehow?

Sounds like a bug in the component. Have you tried contacting the author for help?

I'm guessing the OnChange event doesn't fire for every keyboard press but only when you confirm entering the date which would probably be by pressing Enter key or when switching focus to some other control. This is probably done to avoid writing multiple values during the typing which would probably be even invalid dates.
